# Inner join relation without using "together"

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

i am trying to filter products by category using a scope and i do that by inner joining the categories
the problem is it only works when i turn together on, which messes up pagination

i recall doing that without a problem
also tried using 'on'=> instead of 'condition'=> inside the with() definition, works pretty much the same only the latter is slower db-wise i think

any ideas?

ps. left joining products on a category is unfortunately not an option

```
<?php

/**
 * ProductCategory model
 */
class ProductCategory extends CActiveRecord
{
    //...
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            //...
            'parent' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ProductCategory', 'parentId'),
            'children' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProductCategory', 'parentId'),
            //...
        );
    }
    //...
}

/**
 * Product model
 */
class Product extends CActiveRecord
{
    //...
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            //...
            'categoriesJunction' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProductCategoriesProducts', 'productId'),
            'categories' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProductCategory', array('categoryId'=>'id'), 'through'=>'categoriesJunction'),
            //...
        );
    }

    /**
     * Category scope
     * 
     * @param mixed Category ids the product must belong to (int or array of int)
     * @return \Product
     */
    public function category($category = null) {
        if ($category) {
            $category = ProductCategory::model()->resetScope()->with('children')->findByPk($category);

            if ($category) {
                $categories = array($category->id);

                if (is_array($category->children)) {
                    foreach ($category->children as $child) {
                        $categories[] = $child->id;
                    }
                }

                $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
                    'with' => array(
                        'categories' => array(
                            'on'=>'categories.id=' . implode(' or categories.id=', $categories),
                            'joinType' => 'inner join',
                            //'together'=>true,
                        ),
                    ),
                ));
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Please add more details about the way you are handling relations between your products and categories (PS : and you should learn how to use `CDBCriteria` and `implode`...)

Comment: Added the relation info for Product and ProductCategory models. I can see I had the "glue" after "pieces" in implode(), but for some reason it works both ways. What is so wrong about CDbCriteria?

Comment: Can you explain how it "messes up pagination"? What does that mean? How do the SQL queries look in that case? One workaround could also be to simply use the `join` property of the `CDbCriteria` (not using the `categories` relation).

Comment: I agree with aboce comment, how does this mess up pagination? Maybe you are looking for 'select'=>false (inside 'categories' section of your criteria array)

Comment: using `join` of `CDBCriteria` would be a nice solution, but granted that this scope is used in multiple places it is not portable enough. together messes with your pagination, long story short: [a discussion on yii forums](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29726-pagination-filter-problem/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
select => false is the way to go

> D.Mill Apr 5 at 9:33
>
> > I agree with aboce comment, how does this mess up pagination? Maybe you are looking for 'select'=>false (inside 'categories' section of your criteria array)

after all I found a quite simple solution that works well for a scope, just changing the scope criteria part to

```
$this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
    'with'=>array(
        'categories'=>array(
            'select'=>'false',
            'on'=>'categories.id=' . implode(' or categories.id=', $categories),
            'joinType'=>'inner join',
        ),
    ),
    'together'=>true,
));
```